# How to move Mac OS application to specific display and also resize automatically?

Tags: macos

Usually when you have multiple monitors, you arrange your apps manually by dragging them to different screens and resizing them manually. Is there a tool to do it in one click or one command/script?

If using osascript, I'm able to find how to change the position and resize this:

```
osascript -e 'tell application "Terminal" to tell window 1 to set bounds to {100, 100, 1200, 500}'
```

How to specify display number?

Thanks

Comment: This article over on iMore lists some 3rd party software apps that enable keyboard shortcuts (and more!) for moving windows around. They might apply to your situation.  https://www.imore.com/manage-your-windows-pro-macos

Answer (score 1):

Over on Superuser there are a number of answers that sound like one or more might help with your search.

Specifically that user was looking for something similar to (the Windows only) Ultramon.

https://superuser.com/questions/100364/mac-tools-for-control-multiple-monitors

MercuryMover sounds like it might do the trick. The answer is rather old but it might give you a starting point for finding something that works a treat for your needs.

Comment: From [Reviews & Comments](https://www.macupdate.com/app/mac/26411/mercurymover#comments_reviews_wrapper), "MercuryMover 2.1.1 (latest version) stop function completely in OSX Sierra. Try to contact the dev but no response or fix"